# jasper-report : Tag to use in String to create an unnumbered list in word

Tags: jasper-reports, rtf, docx

Take a regular String in java containing the following :

```
 String test = "hello I'm a list [ul][li]item1[li]item2[/ul]";
```

Now suppose I want to use this string for printing in an html document all I have to do is replace the [] by <> and I'm in business.  But I also want to use this string in a jasper report that export to a docx format.  If I want to have a unnumbered list to appear in word what kind of replacement should I use ?  Is that even possible ?

I've been thinking to use RTF tags that I read about here

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod#RTF-Document-Formatting-Commands

Answer (score 0):

This sort of approach is misguided.  You should hold your data separate from how it is rendered and allow Jasper to render the HTML or RTF accordingly.

If you modified your data structure to be something like the following your rendering in different formats would be a lot easier:

```
<data>
<heading>hello I'm a list</heading>
<items>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</items>
</data>
```